# How to deploy a react app on base as well as a subdirectory path?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I want to deploy my react app on `/` as well as `/subdir`.
There is a way to deploy it on `/subdir` by using basename in react-router and changing `"homepage":"/subdir"` in package.json.

Now this app is to be deployed on docker using nginx. So anyone using the image will have to use exact `subdir` by using nginx reverse proxy.

And also it'll fail to be available from basepath(`/`). So user should have flexibility to pass subdir path. I cannot find a way to do this on runtime.

Till now I've tried subdirectory deployment, which restricts me from running my docker image at basepath(`/`)

I've looked a lot into this problem but couldn't find any solution so far.

Edit::
So my app is deployed at path `/dashboard`. The image is pushed to gcr.

Here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.6'

services:
   explorer:
      image: my-image
   container_name: my-container
   ports:
      - 3030:80
```

[image]